# Metric field equations for the Jordan-Brans-Dicke action

Tags: general-relativity, lagrangian-formalism, metric-tensor, variational-calculus, modified-gravity

Considering the Jordan-Brans-Dicke action:

$$S=\int d^4x\sqrt{-g}\left(\phi R+\frac\omega\phi(\partial\phi)^2+\mathfrak{L_{m}}(\psi)\right).$$

I was trying to get the metric field equations by varying the metric and got this:

$$ -\frac{1}{2}g_{\mu\nu}R+R_{\mu\nu}+\frac{\omega}{\phi^2}[-\frac{1}{2}g_{\mu\nu}(\partial\phi)^2+\partial_\mu\phi\partial_\nu\phi]-\frac{1}{2\phi}g_{\mu\nu}\mathfrak{L_{m}}(\psi)=0 $$

I varied the terms $\sqrt{-g}$, $R_{\mu\nu}$ , $g^{\mu\nu}$ and $\partial_\mu \phi \partial_\nu \phi g^{\mu\nu}$. If we are only conserned for the equations of the metric field then this is it right? If I wanted the equations for the gravitational field we would have to vary w.r.t. the metric and the field $\phi$ right?

EDIT: On the 2nd Leibniz rule I considered:

$$ -\nabla^{\alpha}\nabla_{\alpha}(g_{\mu\nu}\phi\delta g^{\mu\nu}) = -g_{\mu\nu}\nabla^{\alpha}\nabla_{\alpha}(\phi) \delta g^{\mu\nu}-g_{\mu\nu}\nabla^{\alpha} (\phi)\nabla_{\alpha}(\delta g^{\mu\nu})-g_{\mu\nu}\nabla_{\alpha} (\phi)\nabla^{\alpha}( \delta g^{\mu\nu})-g_{\mu\nu} \phi \nabla^{\alpha}\nabla_{\alpha}(\delta g^{\mu\nu}) $$

I pulled out the metric so I dont have to deal with 6 terms. The ones we want are only the first and second in the RHS of this equation

Comment: What happened to /phi R term??

Comment: I divided the whole equation by $\phi$ and that one would be the first term that appears

Comment: Τhats wrong. You have to integrate by parts.

Comment: You have already applied the first covariant derivative. You have to do it once again with the other covariant derivative.

Comment: What do you mean? I applied both of them already. What am I confusing where?

Comment: You applied both of them at the same time.

Comment: I applied $ \nabla_{\alpha}$ first to $g_{\mu\nu} \phi \delta g^{\mu\nu}$ and then $\nabla^{\alpha}$ to the 2 terms that we get from the first covariant derivative, since one of them is the covariant derivative of the metric tensor, which then gives me 4 terms.

Comment: Check my answer here, may help: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/128501/derivation-of-fr-field-equations-problem-with-integration-by-parts/502419#502419

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The $\delta(\phi R)$ term will be:

$$\delta(\phi R) = \delta(\phi g^{\mu\nu}R_{\mu\nu}) = \phi\delta g^{\mu\nu}R_{\mu\nu} +\phi\delta R_{\mu\nu}g^{\mu\nu} $$

The term:  $\phi\delta g^{\mu\nu}R_{\mu\nu}$ is ready, here the variation of the inverse metric tensor is already a multiplying factor. Now the second term is:

$$\phi\delta R_{\mu\nu}g^{\mu\nu}  = \phi (g_{\mu\nu}\Box - \nabla_{\mu}\nabla_{\nu})\delta g^{\mu\nu}$$

where i've used the Palatini Identity. Now we have for example for the box term:

$$\phi g_{\mu\nu}\Box\delta g^{\mu\nu} = \phi g_{\mu\nu}\nabla^{\alpha}\nabla_{\alpha}\delta g^{\mu\nu} =\nabla^{\alpha}(\phi g_{\mu\nu}\nabla_{\alpha}\delta g^{\mu\nu}) -\nabla^{\alpha}\phi g_{\mu\nu}\nabla_{\alpha}\delta g^{\mu\nu}  $$

The first term is a total derivative. We will ignore it as a boundary term. Now we use Leibniz rule once again:

$$-\nabla^{\alpha}\phi g_{\mu\nu}\nabla_{\alpha}\delta g^{\mu\nu} = -\nabla^{\alpha}\nabla_{\alpha}(g_{\mu\nu}\phi\delta g^{\mu\nu}) + g_{\mu\nu}\delta g^{\mu\nu}\nabla^{\alpha}\nabla_{\alpha}(\phi)$$

where i've used metric compatibillity. So we have:

$$\phi g_{\mu\nu}\Box\delta g^{\mu\nu} = g_{\mu\nu}\delta g^{\mu\nu}\nabla^{\alpha}\nabla_{\alpha}(\phi) = g_{\mu\nu}\delta g^{\mu\nu} \Box \phi$$
One has to do the same procedure for the two covariant derivatives. The other terms seem correct.

The problem here is that the Ricci Scalar is coupled with $\phi$. When i first came across such coupling terms i had the same problem. In the context of General relativity, the action is:

$$S = \int d^4x \sqrt{-g}R. $$

The variation gives rise to the term $g^{\mu\nu}\delta R_{\mu\nu}$. We can show that this term is a total derivative term and cancel it. In the context of Brans Dicke (or other geometric modifications to Einstein Gravity, $f(R)$ for example, Horndeski, or matter fields non-minimally coupled to gravity) this term is no longer a total divergence. Here, this term is : $\phi\delta R_{\mu\nu}g^{\mu\nu}$. $\phi$ makes things tricky, we cannot now discard this term as it is, it is not a total derivative term. Thus, we follow the procedure i described above.

Regarding the second part of the question, yes you have to vary also with respect to $\phi$. Here $\phi$ is not a matter field, it is a geometric quantity.

Comment: Thank you! In all the action variations I´ve done so far R wasn´t coupled with any other field so I just do it fast by claiming the Palatini identity and Gauss theorem and say it´s zero.

Comment: I understand your situation 100%. Been there, done exactly the same thing.

Comment: Just one thing, isn´t there a $g_{\mu\nu}$ missing in the 4th equation you wrote on the 1st term of the RHS?

Comment: Of course!! Thank you for pointing it out!

Comment: Sorry could you elaborate in how you did the second Leibniz rule? I get 4 terms when I distribute the two covariant derivatives for this term: $\nabla^{\alpha} \nabla_{\alpha}(g_{\mu\nu} \phi \delta g^{\mu\nu})$ considering the metric compatibility I took the metric out directly and got the other 4 terms, do 2 of them cancel each other out?

Comment: $\nabla_{\alpha}$ acts on the variation. I moved this derivative in front of all terms and subtracted $g_{\mu\nu}\delta g^{\mu\nu}\Box \phi$ (Leibniz rule).

Comment: You have to kill the total derivative term in the first Leibniz rule in order to proceed.

Comment: Yes I did that. For your first Leibniz rule  I considered the term $\nabla^{\alpha}( \phi g_{\mu\nu} \nabla_{\alpha} (\delta g^{\mu\nu}))$ and distributed the $\nabla^{\alpha}$  on the 3 terms and one of them vanished because of metric compatibility and rearranging that equation got me to your fist Leibniz rule. I ignored the term that has the total derivative. I tried the same procedure using $ \nabla^{\alpha} \nabla_{\alpha} (g_{\mu\nu} \phi \delta g^{\mu\nu})$ but there are extra terms

Comment: How?? Please write these terms.

Comment: I will write them

Comment: Could anyone explicitly do variation with respect to $\phi$?

Comment: Why don't you ask a question on the topic so someone might help you?